# A seemingly trivial property of continuous functions differentiable at the origin (PART 2)

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a *continuous* function such that $F(0)=0$, $F$ is differentiable at $0$ and $DF(0)$ is invertible. Is there an elementary way to show that for all $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that
$$
DF(0)(B_{(1-\epsilon)\delta})\subset F(B_\delta)\subset DF(0)(B_{(1+\epsilon)\delta}),
$$
where $B_r$ is the ball of radius $r$ centered in $0$?

Two observations:

1. The second inclusion $F(B_\delta)\subset DF(0)(B_{(1+\epsilon)\delta})$ is obvious.
2. The first inclusion is also true but the proof I came up with is non-trivial and relies on an application of Brouwer's fixed point theorem.

**NOTE**: I previously asked almost the same question here [A seemingly trivial property of differentiable functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429585/a-seemingly-trivial-property-of-differentiable-functions) but I forgot to mention that $F$ is continuous. In that case, as the accepted [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/429590) shows, there is a simple counterexample. For continuous functions however the result *is* true, I just want to know whether there is an easy proof that avoids Brouwer.

Comment: I think you can use the inverse function theorem, and deduce the first inclusion by applying the second inclusion for the inverse function $F^{-1}$.

Comment: No I don't think I can. The function is not $C^1$, only continuous and differentiable at the origin.

Comment: I see. I leave my comment for the benefit of others.

Comment: Don't you want to assume $F(0)=0$ ?

Comment: From a reverse mathematics standpoint, one could ask whether the result is provable in $\mathsf{RCA}_0$. If not, then Brouwer's fixed-point theorem would be needed in a strong sense.

Comment: @BK Yep, edited.